# When I use lazy loading to import components, I encountered chunkLoadError：chunk loading xxx failed.(error: https://s.thsi.cn/xxx.js)?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, lazy-loading

When I use lazy loading to import components, I encountered chunkLoadError.
There are three types errors I meet:

1、js run error

eg.ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk SimpleMainIndex failed.\n(error: https://s.thsi.cn/cd/website-basic-base-container/dist/js/SimpleMainIndex.a6c169c4.js)

2、request timeout

eg.ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk SimpleMainIndex failed.\n(timeout: https://s.thsi.cn/cd/website-basic-base-container/dist/js/SimpleMainIndex.a6c169c4.js)

3、js missing

eg.ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk SimpleMainIndex failed.\n(missing: https://s.thsi.cn/cd/website-basic-base-container/dist/js/SimpleMainIndex.a6c169c4.js)

Our page visit is probably at the million level,the chunkloaderror ratio is about 1%.

import method:
const comp = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "SimpleMainIndex" */ '~/components/mainIndex/index.vue');
const res = await comp().default;

my project webpack version:4.46.0,vue version: 2.6.X

do you meet this error?

Comment: If the error is 1% of 1million page loads, it is 99% related to server operation and very unlikely related to Vue or Webpack